# Sumar múltiples columnas

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo esta tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tesis.oteaderos_2017_habitat
(
otead integer,
cod_111 numeric,
cod_112 numeric,
cod_121 numeric)
```

Quiero hacer una consulta que sume los valores de los campos que empiezan por "cod". Escribo lo siguiente:

```
SELECT otead, sum(h.cod_111,
h.cod_112,
h.cod_121) as artificial
FROM  tesis.oteaderos_2017_habitat h
group by otead
```

Pero me devuelve este error:

```
ERROR:  no existe la función sum(numeric, numeric, numeric)
LINE 1: SELECT otead, sum(h.cod_111,
                      ^
HINT:  Ninguna función coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos. Puede ser necesario 
agregar conversión explícita de tipos.
```

He intentado hacer un `cast`, pero tampoco he sabido hacerlo bien, porque sigue diciendo lo mismo.

¿Cómo debería hacer la consulta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te está diciendo que no existe ninguna función llamada `SUM()` que tenga tres parámetros. La función `SUM()` toma un único parámetro, por lo que si quieres calcular la suma de varios campos, debes sumar entre sí las sumas independientes de cada uno de ellos.

La consulta SQL quedaría como sigue:

```
SELECT
    otead,
    SUM(h.cod_111) + SUM(h.cod_112) + SUM(h.cod_121) as artificial
FROM  tesis.oteaderos_2017_habitat h
GROUP BY otead
```